# 409 error (Conflict) when trying to insert an image into a post

Tags: images, errors

I've uploaded a Wordpress site to the live server and I get this error whenever I try to insert an image into a post:

> **Conflict**
>        The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>        Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>        More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>        Apache/2.2.0 (Fedora) Server at www.sitename.com Port 80

Just to be clear - the error appears only when i try to **insert** the image into the page. I can upload it to Media just fine. Also, it happens with external images as well as local ones. It seems enough to have an IMG tag with something in the SRC attribute for this to happen.

It's very weird, I've installed Wordpress on many servers and never had this happen before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with ModSecurity settings blocking some of the Wordpress scripts.

Comment: Please explain how you fixed it to turn this fragment into an answer.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don't know the exact fix - I sent an email to the people responsible for configuring the server and they fixed it. Hopefully my answer above will point people in the right direction at least.